# how to get data from input type=file , modify it, and then insert it in this input js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have file input button( input type=file ). lets say i choose image. i want to get this image from input, modify it, and after that insert this modified image in the same file input.

1. get image from input file
2. modify it //doesnt matter how
3. insert this image into my file input button // change old image to new one

Comment: Where is your attempt?  Also, are you trying to change the file contents?   Input[type='file'] has some limitations because of risks of injection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881212/jquery-javascript-based-image-editor

Comment: thanks for reply. I didnt post code cause just interested how can i get data from input file and modify it. yes, im trying to change input file content( resize the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="filesToUpload"> Select all photo files you need.</label>
        <br>
        <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="" />
        <br><br>
</form>
```

jQuery (I would als use [an image lib](http://camanjs.com/))

```
var input = $( "input:file");

Caman(input, function () {
    this.brightness(10);
    this.contrast(30);
    this.sepia(60);
    this.saturation(-30);
    this.render();
  });
```